# How to execute a shell command from a php script

Tags: php, shell-exec

I would like to create a php script to execute a shell command and return its output. The server requires a private key. When I first decided to test this out I created this:

```
<?php
$command = "ls";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

That worked just fine. But when I changed `$command` to the command I really wanted to run:

```
$command = "/etc/init.d/mycontrollerd status /etc/mycontrollerconfig";
```

it gave me this output:

```
You need root privileges to run this script
```

My guess is I need to use `sudo`. Of course that will require putting the pem file somewhere on the server. Assuming I do that, what exactly should `$command` be? Should I use `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, `system()` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter which php function you use to start the script - what lacks is the authorization of your user account.

Either use sudo (preconfigure the web server user to run the exact command without password via `visudo`, and prefix the command with `sudo`) or set up a setuid script that executes the command on itself.

Comment: While it *also* matters that the user account must be authorized, that doesn't mean there isn't a best choice for the PHP function to use. Which is best?

Comment: @Kenneth Vogt `exec`, since it doesn't needlessly involve the shell and returns the result, or `passthru`, which directly outputs the result, but would require some modification of the original code.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need to do is set your web server to run as a specific user (other than 'nobody' for example), or give that user permissions to what you want to execute.

See also:  [PHP shell_exec() and sudo: must be setuid root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230391/php-shell-exec-and-sudo-must-be-setuid-root)

Comment: This begs the question: How do you "set your web server to run as a specific user other than 'nobody'"?

Comment: @Kenneth Vogt, how should I know, you didn't specify which server you were using.  If you are using Apache, check the `User` and `Group` configuration directives.  (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#user)  If you can't get that working, the appropriate place to ask is ServerFault.com.